# Prove that $<$ defined above on $\hat f$ is a well-ordering of order type $\epsilon_{0}$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

If $f,g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ define $f<g \iff \exists M:\forall x>M$, $f(x)<g(x)$
[Does this mean that $g$ dominates $f$].

Now define $\hat f$ to be the smallest set of functions containing $\Bbb N[x]$ and closed under the operation $f\mapsto x^{f}$ and $(f,g)\mapsto f+g$

[e,g $x^{x^{3x+2}+5x^{x}}+2x+4\in \hat f$, but $(x+1)^{x} \notin \hat f$] 
I want to prove that $<$ defined above on $\hat f$ is a well-ordering of order type $\epsilon_0$.

My attempt:

Recall that  a set  $x$ is said to be well oredered by $<$ if $x$ is linearly ordered by $<$ and has the property if $A\subseteq X$ non- empty then $A$ contains a least element i,e $\exists x \in A : x\le a ,\forall a \in A$.

I need to show that $(\hat f,<)\cong (\epsilon_{0},<)$ to ensure that it is a well ordering of type $\epsilon_0$ that is i need to find a Bijection?

Comment: If $\hat{f}$ is the smallest such set, then $x^{x^{3x+2+5x^x}}+2x+4 \notin \hat{f}$ in contradiction with one of your examples. Is $\hat{f}$ also closed under summation? However my answer below explains how to find a minimal $f$.

Comment: The order type rather feels like ${\omega_0}^{\omega_0.2}$ to me. $\varepsilon_0$ would require the set to be stable under summation.

Comment: Think about the "plug in $\omega$" function - e.g. send $x^{x+1}$ to $\omega^{\omega+1}$. This doesn't always work - think about $1+x$ versus $x+1$ - so you need to restrict attention to elements of $\hat{f}$ with a particular form ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber would I apply cantors normal form to the elements of $\hat f$?

Comment: @nombre i think the set is also stable under summation as you pointed out

Comment: @Gibberish That's the goal. However, nombre and abcdef are right - your definition is *not* closed under addition. You need to close $\mathbb{N}[x]$ under *both* $x\mapsto x^f$ and $(f, g)\mapsto f+g$. Otherwise you can't get a function like $x^x+x$. That is, your definition of $\hat{f}$ right now gives the set of functions of the form $x^{x^{...^{x^p}}}$ with $p\in\mathbb{N}[x]$.

Comment: I feel like my lecturer may have made a mistake when giving me this problem, if i was to assume that it was closed under both of those operations, how would  i continue?

Comment: I have updated my post to include that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If $\hat{f}$ is also stable under sum, then you could try to prove that the map recursively defined on $\varepsilon_0$ by $\varphi(0) = 0$ and $\varphi(\sum \limits_{k=0}^p \omega^{\alpha_k}.n_k) := \sum \limits_{k=0}^p x^{\varphi(\alpha_k)}.n_k$ is an isomorphism.

The best way to do this is to prove it by induction on the least integer $n_{\lambda}$ such that $\lambda \in x_n:= \omega^{\omega^{... \omega}}$ where $\omega$ appears $(n+1)$-times: prove that $\varphi$ is well-defined on $x_n$, strictly increasing, and that $\hat{f} = \bigcup \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \varphi(x_n)$.